# jQuery UI dialog + Ajax fails with IE 6-7-8

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i have problem with jQuery-ui Dialog when using ajax

```
$.ajax({ 
                        url: "folders.php", 
                        cache: false,
                        data: {
                                'do' : 'Ajax'
                                ,'_a' : 'ChangeMoviesFolder'
                                ,'MovieIDS' : MovieIDS
                                ,'toFolderID' : toFolderID
                                ,'fromFolderID' : fromFolderID
                        },
                        context: document.body, 
                        open: function(event, ui) {

                            alert('open');
                        },
                        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                             // Handle the beforeSend event
//                          alert("responseText: "+errorThrown.message);

                           },

                        success: function(data){
                            $('input.checkMovie').attr('checked',0);
                                $("#resultsTable").find('tr.selectable-row').removeClass('active');


                            if (data == '1')
                            {

                                window.location = WWW_ROOT+'movies.php?do=List&FolderID='+toFolderID;
                            }
                             $dialog.dialog("close"); 
                      }});
```

when using IE ajax never get to **success** option
in error i got

"This method cannot be called until the open method has been called"

Its happen only in IE.

Does any one may know what the problem might be ?

(all vars are ok and works perfectly in FF & chrome)

thanks.

---

after alot of checking ajax not working at all with IE

i tried

> $.ajax({ 
>                 url: 'movies.php',      data: "do=UpdateMovies&_a=SetStatus",
>         success: function(data){
>             alert('something');
>
> ```
>   }});
> ```

inside a function , no vars , i have tried it just like in

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

and its just dont get executed any help will be appricated

Comment: Are you opening the dialog before calling the close?  Before this request is made maybe?

Comment: yes dialog is opened , user select folder to remove row to
and then click "move rows" , the move rows button activate the ajax request

Answer (score 7):

There's a conflict between jQuery 1.4 and Sarissa.

Is sarissa.js included on the page?

Similar reports:

https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/RF-8282

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3608

http://code.google.com/p/jstree/issues/detail?id=430

This change to Sarissa seems to work.

```
// _SARISSA_XMLHTTP_PROGID = Sarissa.pickRecentProgID(["Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"]);
 _SARISSA_XMLHTTP_PROGID = Sarissa.pickRecentProgID(["MSXML2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"]);
```

Comment: Worked for me and saved my website launch (after we ported to jQuery from Prototype the day before going live!). Thanks a million.

Comment: I had seen those links, but didn't put together the common thread. Thank you so much.

Comment: Had this issue with a Salesforce VisualForce site that includes Sarissa automatically. The above solution resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to us the Developer tools in IE to step through your code and see what is getting executed and what the variable values are? IE 8 has a great set of tools built right in by hitting F12.

[Working with the Internet Explorer Developer Tools](http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2009/10/24/Working-with-the-Internet-Explorer-Developer-Tools.aspx)

Comment: yes i have tried , no error using IE , all params working and have values , the only problem is using $.ajax inside a dialog box