# jQuery.get() works on IE, but jQuery.post() does not

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a very strange problem. I'm making a pretty standard ajax-call with jQuery, but it refuses to work with Internet Explorer 7.

The code is following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: updateUrl,
  cache: false,
  type: 'post',
  data: params, 
  success: function(data){
    handleResponse(data);
  }
 });
```

The weird part is that, if I change the type to 'get' everything works correctly. I have determined that with 'post' IE does not send anything to the server at all.

I'm also setting all kind of headers to prevent caching, but they have no effect on the 'post' problem.

Comment: does it work in other browsers?

Comment: Have you used Fiddler to inspect whether or not IE is sending the POST correctly, and what the server is responding with?  It may be a problem on the server end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to track this problem down. Ultimately the problem was a conflict between Sarissa and jQuery. A solution can be found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351289/jquery-ui-dialog-ajax-fails-with-ie-6-7-8). After the proposed fix, IE worked again.

The other problem was also the IE7 in CrossOver. It seems to be faulty in overall, because even with the fix it refused to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, according to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for `$.post()` (which is shorthand for the AJAX call):

> Pages fetched with POST are never
>   cached

Try setting a dataType for the returned data and add an error handler that will alert any errors:

```
$.ajax({
  url: updateUrl,
  cache: false,
  type: 'post',
  data: params, 
  success: function(data){
    handleResponse(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr,textStatus){
    alert(textStatus);
  }
 });
```

Also, are you sure that the page that it's posting to is getting POST variables and not only GET variables?

Comment: Also, did you try setting `type: 'post',` to `type: 'POST',`? Maybe it makes a difference to IE7.

Comment: Unfortunately those changes have no difference.

Comment: @M.L.: Did the error alert anything? Are there any errors shown in IE?

Comment: I may have a completely different problem here. I'm using IE7 in Linux with CrossOver and it may be that it just does not work correctly. I have to check this in Windows later.

Comment: @M.L.: That's a good point. It may have something to do with that.